# Empty __init__.py when deployed with Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, pip, artifactory, python-packaging

I have a pretty weird case - even don't know where to look.

I have a Python package e.g. `my_utils` which is uploaded to artifactory (same as PyPi).

Project structure:

```
my_utils
    __init__.py
    first_package
        __init__.py
        some_file.py
```

**first_package/some_file.py**

```
def do_job():
    print("job_done")
```

**my_utils/**init**.py**

```
from first_package.some_file import do_job
```

Package deployed using pretty standard way:

**setup.py**

```
from os import path
import setuptools

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

with open(path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='my_utils',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='my_utils',
    setup_requires=['wheel'],
    long_description=long_description,
    include_package_data=True,
    url='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    license='MIT',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    package_data={
        '': ['*.*']
    },
    install_requires=[],
    zip_safe=False
)
```

To deploy - I use command:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r local
```

So when I do `pip install my_utils` - I can do the following:

```
# env with my_utils installed

from my_utils import do_job

do_job() # job done
```

Now when I use this package in the application that is deployed with Docker and contains it in requirements:

**requirements.txt**

```
my_utils==1.0.0
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ...
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN PIP install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

When I enter the container i have file `my_utils/__init__.py` **empty**. And the import failed:

```
  File "/app/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from my_utils import do_job
ImportError: cannot import name do_job
```

And the direct import works fine:

```
from my_utils.first_package.some_file import get_job
```

For now, I switched to "direct" import without a shortcut but really interesting why that can happen

When I go inside the container - I see that file `__init__.py` is empty. But when re-installed it gets content

```
$: docker exec -it my_app bash
# du /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_utils/__init__.py
0       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_utils/__init__.py

# pip uninstall my_utils
# pip install my_utils

# du /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_utils/__init__.py
4       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_utils/__init__.py

# cat /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_utils/__init__.py
from first_package.some_file import do_job
```

Comment: Is it a typo or is your `__init__.py` really missing a dot (`.`) here: `from .first_package.some_file import do_job`

Comment: There is no dot, but it works without a dot when installed without Docker. (in venv). Will try with a dot

Comment: @Wombatz, adding a dot didn't make a change. See also additional update in the answer. there is a weird disappear of content in `__init__.py`

Comment: Please include the steps you take to build the package. I see neither `setup.py` nor `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: @Wombatz, updated with setup.py In the deploy there is no something special

Comment: Does it still work, when you install `my_utils==1.0.0` inside the docker container? Maybe version `1.0.0` is broken but not the newest version

Comment: @Wombatz, I put here `1.0.0` just for example. I bumped the version several times. (including the one when tried `__init__.py` with dot). So version here seems to be OK

Comment: @Wombatz even more of that - I have another project that uses this library (also Dockerized) and there it's working  will try to compare dockerfiles...